# Printing HTML element on console returning NULL (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
function test(){
  let cart1 = document.getElementById('cart1');
  console.log(cart1);
}
```

I have created a test function to print the contents inside a `<p>` tag on to the console.

And this is my HTML.

```
<body> 
  <p id="cart1">
    hello world
  </p>
  <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is what gets printed on the console:

> null

Why is this happening?

Comment: When and how are you calling `test()`?

Comment: How are you calling `test`? (FYI your code works if you call `test`. I'm surprised it's returning `null` however.)

Comment: I have executed your code and I don't get null. The value of 'p' gets printed on the console. What may be happening in your case is that the JavaScript code is getting executed before the page is fully loaded. And as a result it is not able to find the element, resulting in null. Consider changing the order of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your `Home.js` like this.

```js
function test() {
  let cart1 = document.getElementById('cart1');
  console.log(cart1);
}

test();
```

```html
<p id="cart1">
  hello world
</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the console is logging `null`.

Comment: I still get null

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your JS code with the following. You've to use innerHTML property to get the text inside from p tag. The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

```
test();

function test(){
  let cart1 = document.getElementById('cart1').innerHTML;
  console.log(cart1);
}
```

Comment: this returns a type error

Comment: `textContent` or `innerText` would be better.

Comment: @DarthTensor, You better look into this [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rajuahmed/1v9db75r/1/). It does not return a type error.

Comment: @Andy yes you're right. There are many ways to complete a task.

Comment: @RajuAhmed it still does for me tho

Comment: @DarthTensor, Did you see the link, I've shared with my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem, I wrote a simple example, and it works fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="cart1">hello world</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      let cart1 = document.getElementById('cart1');
      console.log(cart1);
    }
    test();
</script>
</html>
```

If he still has problems, I suggest using the `onload` event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="cart1">hello world</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = () => {
       let cart1 = document.getElementById('cart1');
      console.log(cart1);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should do console.log(cart1.innerHTML);

Comment: I did it ...it returns an error